# Json encode parameters issue

Tags: php

I'm receiving a error message explaining the following error.

```
json_encode() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given</p>
```

When I make the call to the json_encode function I have all three of the paramters set with accpted values.

I"m trying to figure out why this is because when I do tests on my code I get all accepted values with this function. Any thoughts? I think it 's something to do with the switch statement but I need further verifcation as well as information on what I'm doing wrong. Can someone enlighten me please?

```
public function output($message, $title, $status)
{
    switch ($status)
    {
        case 'Error':
            array('status' => 'Error');
            break;
        case 'Notice':
            array('status' => 'Notice');
            break;
        case 'Success':
            array('status' => 'Success');
            break;
    }
    echo json_encode($status, $title, $message);
}
```

Comment: You're giving the bad parameters. see [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: I would suggest you use `strtoupper` function within the switch and your array wihtin the switch goes to no where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I suggest and would work :

```
public function output($Message='', $Title='', $Status=''){
    #   We make sure our status is perfect.
    #   We make sure our status will always be what we want and not something different by mistake.
    #   We default to "Error".
    switch(strtoupper($Status)){
        default:
            $Status = 'error';
        break;

        case 'NOTICE':
            $Status = 'notice';
        break;

        case 'SUCCESS':
            $Status = 'success';
        break;
    }

    #   We output the content as JSON
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status'    => $Status,
        'title'     => $Title,
        'message'   => $Message
    ));

    #   Done - 0 mean the page end with no error (PHP error !)
    exit(0);
}
```

Output:

`output('this is my message', 'this is my title', 'error');`

```
{
    "status" : "error",
    "title" : "this is my title",
    "message" : "this is my message"
}
```

Documentations:

- [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)
- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)
- [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: I like this one as well however what is the purpose of the switch above with the strtoupper function and the fact of the header function why is it important to have those.

Comment: @KevinSmith The `strtoupper` function will make sure that if you write "eRroR", it will still work and become "ERROR". The switch will search for "ERROR" and not "eRroR" and will work in the end even if you do a mistake. The header is important. It tell the browser/client what kind of content is coming. Some client will not accept your server answer if the content-type is not set properly.

Comment: Is doing default: case 'ERROR': an acceptable syntax for the switch statement

Comment: @KevinSmith Yes. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php. You can even do multiple case one after one.

Comment: I know this but I thought default takes the place of the case.

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree that you could use only `default` without the `case 'ERROR'` in this case. However, the strtoupper has a reason to be there. If you type in your code let's say "succesS". Without the strtoupper, you'll default it to error but you really want to show success here, not error. It's mistake-proof.

Comment: No! the problem is, that the default block will never entered if it is on top of the switch block. Note that using case insensitive identifiers in programming languages is usually done to keep the code readable. Meaning it prevents you from defining a function `testSetup()` and `TestSetup()`. But this is not done to be `mistake-proof`. (LOL)

Comment: @hek2mgl No. The default block will be trigger. No need to have it at the bottom, get your fact straight. Try it. The upper case in this case is not about "readable code".

Comment: @DavidBélanger I've tried it just a moment ago. You are right. Are you sure that this is the same for C ? Will try it

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks. Also the same for C, yes. You just have to make sure the break statement is here, if not, won't work and will default at the end no matter what.

Comment: +1 for showing me this. thanks! never thought that is is true :) .About the case insensitive identifiers (or modes) I would not do so, but of course there are advantages as well

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree on one of your point also... if you wrote `sucCeess` let's say... it's a mistake the programmer did. However, you can avoid the time to fix it only by putting `strtoupper` or `strtolower`. It's time saving and you fix it when you have the chance ... but in the mean time, it'll work.

Comment: One of the old UNIX programming rules (by Mr. Dennis Ritchie and friends) says: If something went wrong, it should crash as loud as possible. I'm with them.

Answer (score 5):

You might looking for something like this:

```
echo json_encode(array($status, $title, $message));
```

or, as others suggested, like this:

```
json_encode(array("status"=>$status, "title"=>$title, "message"=>$message))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only encode a single data structure. If you have three bits of data that you want to encode, then you must combine them into a single data structure first. For example:

```
echo json_encode(Array("status" => $status, "title" => $title, "message" => $message));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do is encode an array?

```
public function output($message, $title, $status)
{
    switch ($status)
    {
        case 'Error':
            array('status' => 'Error');
            break;
        case 'Notice':
            array('status' => 'Notice');
            break;
        case 'Success':
            array('status' => 'Success');
            break;
    }
    echo json_encode(array($status, $title, $message));
}
output('messageval', 'titleval', 'statusval');
```

that will output JSON like:

```
["statusval", "titleval", "messageval"]
```

or there is also this:

```
public function output($message, $title, $status)
{
    switch ($status)
    {
        case 'Error':
            array('status' => 'Error');
            break;
        case 'Notice':
            array('status' => 'Notice');
            break;
        case 'Success':
            array('status' => 'Success');
            break;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status, 'title'=>$title, 'message'=>$message));
}
output('messageval', 'titleval', 'statusval');
```

which will output something similar to:

```
{"message":"messageval", "title":"titleval", "status":"statusval"}
```

Also, your switch block will do nothing since you are not using the array produced by array().

Comment: Which means I could completely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Read, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php what are you doing with switch?nothing!! what it means? 
**case 'Error':
array('status' => 'Error');**

I think you want something like following,

```
public function output($message, $title, $status)
{
    switch ($status)
    {
        case 'Error':
            array('status' => 'Error');
            break;
        case 'Notice':
            array('status' => 'Notice');
            break;
        case 'Success':
            $output =  $title . $message;
            echo json_encode($output);
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't work. In case `$status` is not `Success`, it will fail. It will output content only when `$status` is equal to `Success`. If the programmer type in by mistake `eRror`, nothing is defaulted and corrected.

Comment: In that case perhaps you don't want json_encode, you just want to `echo "Error occur";` so, i just posted to help him, he has to do exact coding.

Comment: Even with `echo "Error occur";`, you are breaking the thing. Reason: if you read the output, you need to read for either json and or your cusetom message.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public function output($message, $title, $status)
    {
        switch ($status)
        {
            case 'Error':
                array('status' => 'Error');
                break;
            case 'Notice':
                array('status' => 'Notice');
                break;
            case 'Success':
                array('status' => 'Success');
                break;
        }
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'title' => $title, 
    'message' =>$message));

    }
```

For more about json_encode refer this [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)